# Drawing a curved dashed line SVG on scroll

Tags: javascript, svg

I've been tasked with adding a dashed line that will link a bunch of illustrations on a page. I've been searching around for a while and came across a few example of drawing normal lines without dashes e.g http://cbron.github.io/blog/2013/12/30/draw-svg-path-on-scroll-tutorial/ which I've used before.

From what I can tell this technique won't work with dashed lines since it's using the stroke dash array to actually animate the drawing of the line. Maybe I'm wrong there?

Is anyone aware of a way to achieve the same effect with a dashed line? Another thing to note is that the line will move across different colour backgrounds.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:
Working solution**

```
var line;
var subPaths = [];

window.onload = function(){
    line = Snap(document.getElementById("drawMe"));
    getSubPaths();
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", drawLine);

function drawLine() {
  var percentDrawn = (document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
  var percentDrawn = Math.round(percentDrawn * 100);

  line.attr({
      d: subPaths[percentDrawn]
  });

}

function getSubPaths(){
    var maxLength = line.getTotalLength();
    for(var i = 0; i<101; i++){
        var currentLength = maxLength*i/100;
        subPaths[i] = line.getSubpath(0, currentLength);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could place a dashed line over the line you want to draw and give it the color of your background: https://jsfiddle.net/t9kqudxo/ However, since you move across different colour backgrounds you might want to split this line in smaller chunks … really depending on your situation you might could also place a copy of your background over the line and "cut transparent dashes" in. It's not perfect but I hope that gives you some ideas.

Comment: @yoshi Cheers! yeah I added the part about the different background because I'd stumbled across that technique. I'm wondering maybe then if snap.svg can handle it by animating the d attribute like in the demo http://snapsvg.io/demos/#globe but I don't think it would work with a scroll interaction.

Comment: There is a simpler way to do it using a dashed mask. [See this answer for a demonstration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540161/make-the-on-scroll-growing-path-to-dashed-line/45541540#45541540)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your link to Snap.svg I came up with this solution:

```
<script src="./snap.svg.js"></script>
<script>

    var line;
    var subPaths = [];
    var percentDrawn = 0;

    window.onload = function(){
        line = Snap(document.getElementById("drawMe"));
        getSubPaths();
        loop();
    }

    function loop(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            line.attr({
                d: subPaths[percentDrawn]
            });
            percentDrawn++;
            if( percentDrawn < 101) loop();
        }, 50);
    }

    function getSubPaths(){
        var maxLength = line.getTotalLength();
        for(var i = 0; i<101; i++){
            var currentLength = maxLength*i/100;
            subPaths[i] = line.getSubpath(0, currentLength);
        }
    }
</script>
```

So what we do is building up an array with sub paths of the original line from the start up to x% of it's total length: `getSubPaths()`.
For this we actually need Snap.svg as it provides us the `getSubpath(0, currentLength)` functionality.

And that's actually all the magic! The `loop()` function is just a `setTimeout` block with an abort-condition once we've finished drawing. The actual drawing however is applying the corresponding subPath from the previous stored array to your line's `d` attribute.

Comment: Nice one, thanks! Do you reckon this will be possible to get working on scroll? So the line is drawn as a user scrolls? I haven't tested what you posted yet but will when I'm back in work.

Comment: You're welcome :) As for the scrolling this should be easy to convert. Whether the percentages come from a timer or a scroll is pretty irrelevant - you could take the logic from the link provided in your question. You can even get a smoother animation if you store more than 100 subPaths by modifying `getSubPaths` accordingly. Let me know if further problems arise :)

Comment: Tried that code, works very well! Thank you! Will report back once I get stuck into the scrolling version.

Comment: Got the scroll version working. I've updated my questions with the working code. Thanks again!